# Upload video chunks to Amazon s3 from MediaStream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, file-upload, safari

I am building an online video recorder app in React, where the user is able to record himself and after that, the video is placed in an S3 bucket. But, Safari has a security feature so if the browser uses too much RAM is refreshes itself and the recorded video is gone. So I would like to upload video chunks to my Laravel backend (and to AWS) as the video goes by and the AWS service should put it together as an mp4 file. Is is possible to do this with any kind of Amazon service?

I already tried Multipart upload but it has a minimum upload limit which is too much for me.